# keep alive errors seen in nginx logs

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gunicorn

In `var/log/nginx/https-error_log` and `var/log/nginx/http-error_log`, I see tens of millions of errors (aggregated over the past several months):

```
client xx.xx.xxx.xxx closed keepalive connection
```

Frequently (but not always) they exist in pairs with the same IP address and timestamp even, e.g.:

```
2016/07/12 19:24:59 [info] 44815#0: *82924 client 82.145.210.66 closed keepalive connection
2016/07/12 19:24:59 [info] 44821#0: *83275 client 82.145.210.66 closed keepalive connection
```

I.e. it seems the same person closed the connection twice at the same point in time? I feel something untoward is going on here. I'm using nginx as a reverse proxy in front of gunicorn (it's a Django app). Can anyone with expertise help me troubleshoot this issue, or speculate what it could be? Alternatively, is it something I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: check the access log, are there ips all using Chrome browser?

Comment: @Lution: Hmm, how would Chrome be a factor? I'll check them and get back to you

Comment: Did you find a solution for this @Hassan?

Comment: @ketan: no man, sadly haven't. Have you? If you haven't, perhaps you could upvote this so someone out there shows more interest in answering this.

Comment: @HassanBaig: Earlier the server would stop logging errors, so I would restart it every time it stopped logging. Then, I tried setting "error_log on" explicitly and commented out the "error_log file [level]" settings that I was using. It's been working fine so far...lets see.

Comment: @ketan: I suppose you can add your experience as an answer if there's enough detail there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

from: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,1680,248005#msg-248005

> This is not a problem to solve, it's just information messages logged
>   by nginx. If it's too verbose for you, consider tuning error_log
>   logging level, see http://nginx.org/r/error_log.
>
> --  Maxim Dounin http://nginx.org/

although for my 2 cents, I'm not sure closing a HTTP/1.1 connection should be "info", more like "debug".

The "in pairs" would be your browser making more than one connection to your server (as is normal). You can verify the number of connections with the developer tools on your browser (under network).

Cameron